# How to print second word alphabetically ? | JAVA

Tags: java, alphabetical-sort

I must ask for inputs from the user (there is not any limit for the input word count) and then the program must print the second word that comes in alphabetical order.

Instructions

> Write a program, that inputs words from the user, until the user enters ‘exit’. When the user enters ‘exit’ the program should display the word that comes second alphabetically. Your program should not be case sensitive.

> "you should only use while loops in your solutions."

Comment: Why not for loops?

Comment: cus it is an assignment and we are not allowwed to use for loops

Comment: Can you please show what code you've written so far? Refer [help] sections on asking homework questions

Comment: @MedElgarnaoui I already posted that answer. Thanks for the endorsement.

Comment: @can it also helps if you provide the exact instructions of the assignment in your question. When posters omit those details, it is my experience that often they leave out subtle, but critical points. Which then causes questions to be partially or incorrectly answered. So, if you don't mind, include the homework instructions as well.

Comment: Write a program, that inputs words from the user, until the user enters ‘exit’. When the user enters ‘exit’ the program should display the word that comes second alphabetically. Your program should not be case sensitive.

Comment: "you should only use while loops in your solutions."

Comment: **You** should try to do this yourself. At least make an attempt.

Comment: Note how it says that YOU should be doing all these things. Do you really think delegating all that pesky programming to other people will prepare you for your exams, or your teacher asking you to explain your input, or heck, adapt it?

Answer (score 2):

Use `Scanner#nextLine()` to capture many space-delimited characters and then split the input into an array of words using `String#split(String)` method.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a sentence:");
String sentence = scanner.nextLine();
String[] words = sentence.split("\\s");
```

Since the words need to be sorted (the question asks for "*the second word that comes in alphabetical order*", we can use various methods. An easy way to do this is by using the Java Streams API.

```
words = Stream.of(words).sorted().toArray(String[]::new);
```

However, for this specific assignment, the OP stated that a `while` loop must be used exclusively. Therefore, using only `while` loop:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < words.length - 1) {

    // Checking the condition for two
    // adjacent words of the array
    if (words[i].compareTo(words[i + 1]) > 0) {

        // Swapping the elements if the next word
        // precedes the current alphabetically
        String temp = words[i];
        words[i] = words[i + 1];
        words[i + 1] = temp;

        // we must keep resetting the index back to zero
        // when a sort occurs
        i = -1;
    }
    i++;
}
```

This is obviously not the most optimized loop, but for academic purposes is clear enough to understand. Using the following sentence as an example (using all lowercase letters for simplicity):

```
the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

Sorted alphabetically should result in

```
[ brown, dog, fox, jumps, lazy, over, quick, the, the ]
```

Going over the first few iterations:

1. In the first iteration, the words "the" and "quick" get swapped and the index *i* is reset back to zero.
2. In the second iteration, (*i* equals zero again), the words "quick" and "the" are in correct order with respect to each other. They are not swapped and the index is incremented by one.
3. In the third iteration (*i*  equals to 1), the words "the" and "brown" are swapped and the index is reset back to zero.
4. In the fourth iteration, (*i* equals zero again), the words "quick" and "brown" are sorted and the index is reset back to zero.

After 4 iterations, the array is partially sorted:

```
[ brown, quick, the, fox, jumps, over, the, lazy, dog ]
```

The process continues until all the words that precede their previous neighbor "bubble up" to the surface. Eventually, all the words will be sorted, the index will be equal to the word count, and the process will stop. For the sentence I provided, it takes 90 iterations for the sorting to complete. This value is not relative to the size of the array. The number of iteration depend on other factors as well

Putting it all together, the solution looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a sentence:");
    String sentence = scanner.nextLine();
    String[] words = sentence.toLowerCase().split("\\s");
    if (words.length < 2) {
        System.err.println("Not enough words were entered");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    int i = 0;
    while (i < words.length - 1) {
        if (words[i].compareTo(words[i + 1]) > 0) {
            String temp = words[i];
            words[i] = words[i + 1];
            words[i + 1] = temp;
            i = -1;
        }
        i++;
    }

    System.out.println("The second word is: " + words[1]);
}
```

For the sentence I used in this example, the output prints out

```
dog
```

---

**Based on this new information:**

> *Write a program, that inputs words from the user, until the user enters ‘exit’. When the user enters ‘exit’ the program should display the word that comes second alphabetically. Your program should not be case sensitive.*

The solution will prompt the user in a loop (using `while` loop as a given constraint).

```
String input = "";
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
boolean isExit = false;
System.out.println("For this problem, you must enter at least two words.");
while (!isExit) {
    System.out.print("Enter a word (type \"exit\" to finish): ");
    input = scanner.next();
    isExit = "exit".equalsIgnoreCase(input);
    if (!isExit) {
        words.add(input.toLowerCase());
    }
}
scanner.close();
```

The code snippet above does a couple, necessary, things:

1. Uses `ArrayList` rather than an array to allow unbounded growth of the collection. "Resizing" an array is a much costlier process than using this Java specialized class.
2. Checks if the word entered is "exit" which is the special-case input to terminate the loop. It is not, and should not, part of the words to be evaluated.

Once the loop operation concludes, the rest of the code should be pretty much the same. We must evaluate the collection of words and check which is the second word in alphabetical order. For this, all we need to do is sort the collection and return whichever word is at index 1. Since I already provided a looping solution to sort the array, I will show better ways to sort a collection. Of course, the easiest way is calling `Collections#sort()`

```
if (words.size() < 2) {
    System.err.println("Not enough words were entered");
    System.exit(-1);
}
Collections.sort(words);
System.out.println("Second word in alphabetical order: " + words.get(1));
```

The caveat with `Collections#sort()` is that the operation modifies the given list. This may or may not be desirable. There might be cases when the original list must be preserved. For those cases, we can use another Java standard library approach using `Streams` API:

```
List<String> sortedWords = words.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println("Second word in alphabetical order: " + sortedWords.get(1));
```

Using the same words I used in my previous version, the result is the same (as expected)

```
Enter a word (type "exit" to finish): the
Enter a word (type "exit" to finish): quick
Enter a word (type "exit" to finish): brown
Enter a word (type "exit" to finish): fox
Enter a word (type "exit" to finish): jumps
Enter a word (type "exit" to finish): over
Enter a word (type "exit" to finish): the
Enter a word (type "exit" to finish): lazy
Enter a word (type "exit" to finish): dog
Enter a word (type "exit" to finish): exit
Second word in alphabetical order: dog
```

Comment: This is the second word in the string, not the second sorted one

Comment: Sorry, didn't read that part. That's still easy though. I will edit.

Comment: ı must write it with while loop

Comment: @can Did you see my comment under your question? I was proven right already. You went from "no loop" to use `while` loop. I will edit this question in about an hour. I have something to do.

Comment: ı added full instruction

Comment: @can, I think I provided an answer to your question. Hopefully the explanation helps understanding how the code works. If I answered your question fully, I will appreciate if you click on the checkmark next to my answer to mark it as the selected answer. ;)

Comment: Instructions never say Arrays.sort cannot be used. Also, updated instructions are asking for a loop of inputs, which are only sorted when exit is given, not of each input line

Comment: @OneCricketeer those details were provided after my answer. I can edit to update based on this information.

Comment: It's fine. Just pointing it out. It's OP's own academic integrity at risk by copying solutions from others

Comment: @GhostCat that might be true, but I have been told countless times that your answer to questions are not just for the OP, but for the many others who will come here in the future looking for answers. It seems like, in the end, you are damn if you do and damn if you don't. I enjoy doing this so I don't mind it as much.